# How to write rule(s) that selects specific facts in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to understand how to structure output in prolog. Suppose I have some facts as follows

```
/* Facts */

course1(lunch, burrito).
side(lunch, chips).
side(lunch, pop).

course1(dinner, pizza).
side(dinner, breadsticks).
side(dinner, water).
```

How can I write a rule something like food(X, Y) where X is lunch or dinner and have it return "burrito, chips, and pop" or "pizza, breadsticks and water" respectively?

Comment: See: [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.let.rug.nl/bos/lpn//)

Comment: Is there somewhere in this that addresses my question? I have been skimming it and am not seeing what you were trying to point me to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you most of the way to your desired food/2.

Predicates
File: `C:/Users/Groot/example.pl`

```
lunch(X) :- course1(lunch,X).
lunch(X) :- side(lunch,X).
```

Example run

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.5.0)


?- working_directory(_,'C:/Users/Groot').
true.

?- [example].
true.

?- lunch(X).
X = burrito ;
X = chips ;
X = pop.
```

If you want all of the items in a list use findall/3.

```
?- findall(X,lunch(X),X).
X = [burrito, chips, pop].
```

---

food/2

> food(X,Y) :- course1(X,Y).
>  food(X,Y) :- side(X,Y).